# How to build DJI OnBoard SDK samples on RPi?

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I've got a DJI M100 and a Raspberry Pi connected by serial according to the onboard SDK quickstart guide.

However I've not done a lot of C/C++ stuff before and I am not sure how to even build the samples they provide.  I did an apt-get install for cmake since it wasn't installed in the Raspbian distribution I am using.

I messed around a bit and ran cmake CMakeLists.txt and it started doing things and this is the output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "2.1.4")
cat: /etc/lsb-release: No such file or directory
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:70 (if):
if given arguments:

"STREQUAL" "16.04"
Unknown arguments specified
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/Onboard-SDK-3.1/sample/Linux/Blocking/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Any ideas?  I can figure out the coding part, but getting the environment set up is holding me up.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The error message isn't in the C++ compiler, it fails when CMake is trying to deduce what needs to be compiled. that's why the error isn't in a .cpp file but in `CmakeLists.txt` line 70.

Answer (score 0):

The Onboard-SDK isn't meant to work on Raspbian, you can check it on the link here - https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/github-platform-docs/Linux/README.html

Maybe it was the reason here. I faced a similar thing even after installing CMAKE on Raspbian.

Answer (score 0):

One simple option is to comment out line 70 or simply remove that line, it might work.

Also it is possible to get Onboard SDK working on Raspbian and I've done so myself by another method.

Here are the commands I used:
sudo apt-get install git

Downloaded and unzipped cmake-3.7.1.tar.gz from https://cmake.org/download/ on desktop

cd /home/pi/Desktop/cmake-3.7.1
./bootstrap
make
sudo make install

Copied Onboard-SDK-3.1 on desktop

cd /home/pi/Desktop/Onboard-SDK-3.1

Copied CMakeLists.txt from /home/pi/Desktop/Onboard-SDK-3.1/sample/Linux/Non-Blocking/CMakeLists.txt to /home/pi/Desktop/Onboard-SDK-3.1 replacing original file
Change Execute Permissions of /home/pi/Desktop/Onboard-SDK-3.1/scripts/build to Anyone
Remove lines 57-59 of CMakeLists.txt in /home/pi/Desktop/Onboard-SDK-3.1

./scripts/build --build-type debug --clean true --lidar-logging off

Answer (score 0):

DJI has apparently added support for Raspbian in January 2017 as they created a branch called `raspberrypi-support` and committed some changes mostly around Makefiles.

Check out the [branch](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK/tree/raspberrypi-support) and the [associated commit](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK/commit/df21bc6a2aac4066ddeb64b15ec50f1db35be60a).